# Show that $|V(G)| \leq \chi (G) \alpha (G) $

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Where $\chi (G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$ and $\alpha (G)$ is the independence number of $G$.

This is one of the exercises in my graph theory notes, and whilst the bound seems to be fairly lenient based off a few examples that I have tested with it I am seemingly unable to construct a proof.

One idea I had was that as $\chi (G) \geq \omega (G)$ (where $\omega (G)$ is the clique number of $G$) then the problem is equivalent to showing $$|V(G)| \leq \omega (G) \alpha (G)  $$ At which point I attempted to follow an argument of supposing $|V(G)| > \omega (G) \alpha (G)  $ and reaching a contradiction, but was unable to. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So $\alpha(G)$ is the maximum size of an independent set, and $\chi(G)$ is the number of independent sets needed to cover the vertices of $G$? And you want to prove that the number of vertices is $\le\chi(G)\alpha(G)$? Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to work with $\chi(G)$. The problems are not equivalent; what you were trying to prove would be sufficient but isn't necessary (in fact, as bof points out, it's not even true).

You can colour the graph with $\chi(G)$ colours. Looking at the vertices of any given colour, they form an independent set. So how many vertices can you have in total?

Comment: Ahh yes thanks very much, I didn't really think of it this way for whatever reason (and just realised my mistake)!

Comment: $|V(G)|\le\omega(G)\alpha(G)$ is not just stronger, it's false, e.g. for $G=C_5.$

Comment: @bof good point, thanks!